# Deriving a recursion relation

Tags: recurrence-relations

I have read a paper which drives a recursion relation as follows and starting from Eq.(1)
$$
[- \frac{d^2}{dr^2}+\frac{l(l+1)}{r^2}+\frac{\omega^2}{4}r^2+\frac{\zeta}{r}]\,\phi_{nl}(r)=E^r_{nl}\,\phi_{nl}
(r) \tag{1}$$

More technically this is the radial Schrodinger equation for a system confined in Harmonic oscillator well. It has been proved that asymptotically correct solutions of the Eq. (1) have the form
$$
\phi_nl(r)=r^{l+1}e^{-\omega r^2/4}\, P^{(p)}_{nl}(r) \tag{2}
$$
where $\omega>0$ and
$$
\lim_{r\to\infty}e^{-\omega r^2/4}\, P^{(p)}_{nl}(r)=\lim_{r\to0} r^{l+1} P^{(p)}_{nl}(r)=0 \tag{3}
$$
There exist analytical solutions of Eq.(2) with
$$
P^{(p)}_{nl}(r)=\sum^p_{i=0}a_i\,r^i \tag{4}
$$
for a discrete set of $\omega_r (p,l)$ and $\zeta_r(p,l)$. By substitution of Eq.(2) and (4) to (1) one gets the recursion relation 
$$
A_ia_i+B_{i+1}a_{i+1}+C_{i+2}a_{i+2}=0 \tag{5}
$$
where
$$
A_i=E-\omega_r(i+l+\frac32) \tag{6}\\
B_i=-\zeta_r \\
C_i=i(i+2l+1)
$$

Now I want to know how the recursion relation is derived by substitution of Eq (2) and (4) into Eq (1)?

**More Precisely:**
If I add some constants to Eq.(1) as follows how the result (Eqs.(5) and (6)) changes?
$$
[- \frac1{2\mu}\frac{d^2}{dr^2}+\frac{l(l+1)}{2\mu r^2}+\frac{\mu\,\omega^2}{4}r^2+\frac{\zeta}{r}]\,\phi_{nl}(r)=E^r_{nl}\,\phi_{nl}
(r) \tag{7}$$

Answer (score 1):

When you substitute in (1) you get a second order o.d.e which can be solved by the power series solution method, where you assume that the solution is in the form of a power series  polynomial with arbitrary coefficients, and by substitution in (1) you can equate the coefficients of each term of degree say k on the LHS with the corresponds coefficients on the RHS. Then you can find a recursion formula which describe this relationship between the coefficients.

Comment: Thanks a lot. However, I didn't understand your mean exactly. Can you introduce me a source which has represented the details? In fact, I just need to know how the result changes if some constants are added to Eq. (1)? To understand what I mean, I wrote this issue at the end of the question

Comment: are you familiar with the series solution method for ode , and how legendre polynomials are obtained ? @NSR

Comment: No. Please see the addendum